# Azure Linked Server:

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, linked-server

I understand that there are a few threads existing on this area, around a local server using `Azure MSSQL` as a linked DB.

My specific issue is the linked server appears, connects and I can view the databases but when trying to go deeper, as in see the tables I get the following error:

> Reference to the database and/or server name in
>   'databasetable.sys.sp_tables_rowset2' is not supported in this version
>   of SQL Server. (Microsoft SQL Error, Error 40515).

I have tried any of the suggestions already mentioned via the other threads, and to no avail can I get any deeper than listing the databases on the Azure server from my local installation of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue when trying to do anything more than simple Select/Insert/update/delete/create Table/Drop table on my SQL Azure databases. It appears you cant do anything that touches the settings of SQL Server or any stored procs that touch system tables, perhaps because the SQL servers could be shared between multiple customers.

There are also [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394102.aspx) areas where Azure SQL has limitations versus a local SQL Server.

Answer (score -2):

We now have this capability using elastic database query, you need to follow two simple steps mentioned as:

Step-1: Create reference to external database 
Step-2: Then create remote table reference in the target database

then you can execute remote queries just the way you do it with SQL Server.

Please refer for step by step details https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical/